# Командная строка в C# SSH

Tags: c#, ssh

У меня вопрос по SshClient. Мне нужно добавить нового сотрудника в облако. После добавления сотрудника в облако в облаке должен быть создан новый файл text.txt с паролем для входа в другие учетные записи. В моей ситуации создается облако, но не создается информация в текстовый файле, не понимаю как решить проблему. В облако добавился новый сотрудник, но информации в текстовом файле не было. Вот код:

```
string ip = "ip";
string user = "login";
string pass = @"password";

SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(ip, 22, user, pass);
sshClient.Connect();

string login_cloud = project.Variables["cloud_login"].Value;
string cloud_password = project.Variables["cloud_password"].Value;
string command= "sudo sh user.sh";
string name_of_employee = project.Variables["employee_name"].Value;
string email_and_password = project.Variables["login"].Value + "       " + project.Variables["all_password"].Value + "https://.ru || https://ru ";
string skype_and_password = project.Variables["login"].Value + "       " + project.Variables["all_password"].Value;


IDictionary<Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes, uint> termkvp = new Dictionary<Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes, uint>();
termkvp.Add(Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes.ECHO, 53);
ShellStream shellStream = sshClient.CreateShellStream("xterm", 80,24, 800, 600, 1024, termkvp);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
shellStream.WriteLine(command);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
shellStream.WriteLine(pass);//Добавил строку подтверждения пароля
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);


shellStream.WriteLine(name_of_employee);//Добавил строку Имя менежера
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
shellStream.WriteLine(" ");//Добавил строку Тел с +998
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
shellStream.WriteLine(email_and_password);//Добавил строку @rulogin___password
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);

shellStream.WriteLine(skype_and_password);//Добавил строку skype___password
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);

shellStream.WriteLine(" ");//Добавил строку pusto
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);

shellStream.WriteLine(" ");//Добавил строку pusto
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
shellStream.WriteLine(" ");//Добавил строку pusto
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
shellStream.WriteLine(login_cloud);//Добавил строку логин от клоуд
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);
shellStream.WriteLine(cloud_password);//Добавил строку пароль от клауда
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);


StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(shellStream);


sshClient.Disconnect();
```

[image: картинка как выгледить добовления сотрудника]

Comment: А bash или sh скрипт написать не? Зачем вот это вот всё? Не вижу чтобы вы какие-либо текстовые файлы создавали.

Comment: @aepot не знаю как сделать и я через зеннопостер работаю там вроде через эту библиотеку надо работать. Если вам не сложно можете полезную ссылку скинуть про bash или sh скрипт?

Comment: `sudo sh user.sh`, user.sh это sh скрипт. Его можно отредактировать так, чтобы он делал то что нужно. А данные вообще аргументами передать. То что вы делаете на C# - крайней степени изврат.

Comment: @aepot ))) сорри но спасибо большое попробую и дам знать если смог

Comment: @aepot не смогу решить через bash или sh скрипт программа зеннопостер не поддерживаеть их только через с# надо

Comment: Ну зпишите cloud_password в файл

Comment: @Виктор не очень понял вас

Comment: _не смогу решить через bash или sh скрипт_ - а что такое `user.sh`? Что внутри? Кстати пустая строка это не `.WriteLine(" ")`, а `.WriteLine()`

Comment: user.sh для создания облака использую это для новога сотрудника

Comment: так это и есть блин sh скрипт! пилите какие-то страшные костыли через заднее место, я пытаюсь вам помочь, а вы сопротивляетесь, как-будто это мне надо, а не вам. ну как хотите, настаивать не буду

Comment: @aepot он уже прописань нету доступа изменить его у меня сказали проста пиши на с#((

Comment: Скопируйте, создайте свой sh скрипт на его основе, или вообще файл на сервере никак не создать? Тогда что за txt вы хотите создать в облаке? Ерунда какая-то. Я не говорю, что на C# ничего писать не надо, я говорю, что надо сделать передачу параметров через аргументы в скрипт, параметры запуска, а не через интерактив. Интерактив предназначен для человека, а не C# костылей.

Comment: @aepot мне проста не дают доступ туда. sudo sh user.sh если прописать эту команду то выйдеть  фото каторый я скинул в описании. когда в ручную прописивая через консоль все работает и он в техтовый файл отправляеть что я прописаль. я тоже самое делаю через с# но он не хочеть в техтовый файл сохронять что я прописал через с#. приколь в том что он создает облоко только(((

Comment: Можете попробовать так `sudo sh user.sh | tee file.txt` тогда весь вывод в консоль продублируется в файл. Больше тут вряд-ли что-то можно посоветовать. Либо создать файл отдельно командой `echo "здесь какой-то текст" > file.txt`

Comment: @aepot спасибо за помочь не помогло sudo sh user.sh | tee file.txt код без ошибки но нету файла(  и если хочу так отправить .WriteLine() выводить ошибку  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'line' of 'ShellStream.WriteLine(string)'"

Comment: странно, ну тогда `.WriteLine("")`